# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Namibia?

Tags: transit-visas, namibia

I have Bulgarian citizenship and permanent residence address in Germany, and I will travel to Botswana for a 10 day trip (scientific conference). The site of our Ministry of External affairs states that I don't need a visa for Botswana.

However, I have to change planes at Windhoek International Airport. Our ministry's site states that I need a visa if I want to visit Namibia, but does not say anything about transit.

I tried to find out on https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/, but did not find a way to input my correct flight details with the layover. So do I need a visa for my travel?

If I have to get the visa, do I get it from a consulate in Germany, or for the consulate accredited for Bulgarians (which is in Vienna)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx)
with your specific details I get this:

> Transit - Namibia (NA)
>
> Visa:
>
> Visa required.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket
> for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the
> international transit area of the airport and have documents required
> for the next destination.

Subject to these conditions, you don't need a visa to transit in Namibia.

Comment: Thank you! I found earlier questions of this type with a reference to Timatic, but the link was broken. When I searched for "timatic" on the Web, I found the link I posted in the question body, and couldn't find a way to enter the transit information there. This one worked for me too.